# Unable to get http response from asp.net core 7 app running inside a linux docker container running on Windows docker desktop (WSL2)

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core, docker-desktop

I am following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I am using VS 2022 on Windows 10 with Docker desktop installed and WSL2 integrated.

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/main/samples/aspnetapp

**QUESTION 1**:
When creating a docker image for some reason I cannot use the default port 80 to run the container (getting this error:
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use.)
so I changed the port in docker file to be 5000.
I ran these commands:

**docker build  -t myaspnetapp:1.0 .**

**docker run -d -it -p 8080:5000 --name myaspnetapp_ctn --net=host myaspnetapp:1.0**

**docker exec -it myaspnetapp_ctn bash**

**curl http://localhost:5000**

When I am inside the container I can get the page ok (with some info about runtime environment, see below)

However, whan I try to use the IP of the container
(I got this by running: docker inspect 3e2b252f01c7: IPAddress": "172.17.0.2") and port: 8080 that is mapped to my host machine:
❯ docker ps
3e2b252f01c7   myaspnetapp:1.0   "dotnet aspnetapp.dll" 0.0.0.0:8080->5000/tcp

When running this
**http://172.17.0.2:8080**

I am not getting the response from within the container:

**This site can’t be reached 172.17.0.2 took too long to respond.**

**QUESTION 2 - Why?**:

One note: I paused my Kasperski anti virus sw and the Windows defender offered me to allow access for Docker Desktop Backend which I allowed (for both Private adn Public networks)

**So what is going on. I cannot do a simple tutorial and I want to go into more advanced scenarios.**

Curl output from inside Docker container:

```
<tr>
    <td>ASPNETCORE_URLS</td>
    <td>http://&#x2B;:5000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Host name</td>
    <td>3e2b252f01c7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Runtime Version</td>
    <td>.NET 7.0.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>OS Version</td>
    <td>Linux 5.15.83.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Dec 14 23:16:32 UTC 2022.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Server IP address</td>
    <td>172.17.0.2</td>
</tr>
```

My docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore --use-current-runtime  

COPY aspnetapp/. .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app --use-current-runtime --self-contained false --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, do you found a solution?